# Dozer not calling my CustomConverters

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Dozer is not calling my `CustomConverter` no matter what I seem to do. I tried to put breakpoints and none of the `CustomerConverter` code is ever called. The objects are converting, all fields but the ones linked to the `CustomConverter` are working.

In my `dozerBeanMapping.xml` file I have:

```
<configuration>
    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="converter.JodaDateToJavaDateConverter">
            <class-a>org.joda.time.LocalDate</class-a>
            <class-b>java.util.Date</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
</configuration>
<mapping type="one-way">
    <class-a>data.SourceObject</class-a>
    <class-b>data.DestinationObject</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="converter.JodaDateToJavaDateConverter">
        <a>myLocalDate</a>
        <b>myJavaDate</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Then for the converter I have:

```
package converter;
public class JodaDateToJavaDateConverter implements CustomConverter
{
    @Override
    public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass)
    {
        if(source == null) 
            return null;
        if(!(source instanceof LocalDate)) 
            throw new MappingException("Misconfigured/unsupported mapping");
        return ((LocalDate)source).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
    }
}
```

And for the Objects I have:

```
package data;
public class SourceObject
{
    private LocalDate myLocalDate = LocalDate.now();

    public void setMyLocalDate(LocalDate myLocalDate) { this.myLocalDate = myLocalDate; }
    public LocalDate getMyLocalDate() { return myLocalDate; }
}

package data;
public class DestinationObject
{
    private Date myJavaDate;

    public void setMyJavaDate(Date myJavaDate) { this.myJavaDate = myJavaDate; }
    public Date getMyJavaDate() { return myJavaDate; }
}
```

I don't think makes any difference but here is the code to start it all:

```
SourceObject mySourceObject = DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance().map(DestinationObject, SourceObject.class);
```

I have no idea why my custom converters are not called...

**UPDATE:** I'm even more confused now. If the fields are the same name for both the Destination and Source Object then everything works. For whatever reason I can't map fields with different names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mapping call, you are mapping DestinationObject to SourceObject, while in the `dozerBeanMapping.xml`, you specify that your custom converter should only be used when mapping SourceObject to DestinationObject, and not the other way round (due to `type=one-way`).

When you use same field names, the general config becomes active, where you specified that every `org.joda.time.LocalDate` should be mapped to a `java.util.Date` (and vice-versa) using your custom converter.